# Handling View State & Side Effects with Lifecycle Awareness in Jetpack Compose MVI Composable

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-compose

I'm working on a stateful Jetpack Compose composable that follows the MVI architecture. I'm using collectAsStateWithLifecycle() to observe the view state from a view model, but I'm unsure about the best approach to collect side effects with lifecycle awareness.

I'd appreciate your insights on:

- The correctness of the current approach.
- Potential improvements or alternative techniques.
- Best practices for collecting viewstate and side effects with lifecycle awareness in
  Jetpack Compose.

```
    @Composable
        fun CountryListScreenContent(callback: (countryName: String) -> Unit) {
            val viewModel: CountryListViewModel = hiltViewModel()
            val countryListViewState by viewModel.viewState.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()
            LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
                viewModel.sideEffect.collect {
                    if (it is CountryListContract.SideEffect.NavigateToDetails) {
                        val countryName = it.countryName
                        callback(countryName)
                    }
                }
            }
            CountryListViewState(viewState = countryListViewState, callback = { it ->
                viewModel.sendIntent(
                    ...
                )
            })
        }
```

Comment: Does your `CountryListViewModel` itself have any access to a CoroutineScope? How do you create it? What does the callback do? It looks a bit to me like the callback-related code belongs in the viewmodel instead of in your compose code.